# Python: Combining itertools and sets to save memory

Tags: python, memory-management, set, python-itertools

so I discovered Sets in Python a few days ago and am surprised that they never crossed my mind before even though they make a lot of things really simple. I give an example later.

Some things are still unclear to me. The docs say that Sets can be created from iterables and that the operators always return new Sets but do they always copy all data from one set to another and from the iterable? I work with a lot of data and would love to have Sets and set operators that behave much like itertools. So Sets([iterable]) would be more like a wrapper and the operators union, intersection and so on would return "iSets" and would not copy any data. They all would evaluate once I iter my final Set. In the end I really much would like to have "iSet" operators.

**Purpose:**
I work with MongoDB using mongoengine. I have articles saved. Some are associated with a user, some are marked as read others were shown to the user and so on. Wrapping them in Sets that do not load all data would be a great way to combine, intersect etc. them. Obviously I could make special queries but not always since MongoDB does not support joins. So I end up doing joins in Python. I know I could use a relational database then, however, I don't need joins that often and the advantages of MongoDB outweigh them in my case.

**So what do you think?** Is there already a third party module? Would a few lines combining itertools and Sets do?

**EDIT:**
I accepted the answer by Martijn Pieters because it is obviously right. I ended up loading only IDs into sets to work with them. Also, the sets in Python have a pretty good running time.

Comment: You can delay the operations e.g., as chained SQLAlchemy queries do. But eventually a set need to be created (an Index in sql terms) otherwise the performance degrades to the quadratic running time for join operations on non-PK columns.

Comment: As far as I know mongoengine also delays certain queries and fetches big data in chunks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sets are just like `dict` and `list`; on creation they copy the references from the seeding iterable.

Iterators *cannot* be sets, because you cannot enforce the uniqueness requirement of a set. You cannot know if a future value yielded by an iterator has already been seen before.

Moreover, in order for you to determine what the intersection is between two iterables, you *have* to load all data from at least one of these iterables to see if there are any matches. For each item in the second iterable, you need to test if that item has been seen in the first iterable. To do so efficiently, you need to have loaded all the items from the first iterable into a set. The alternative would be to loop through the first iterable from start to finish *for each item* from the second iterable, leading to exponential performance degradation.

Comment: +1, but it is also worth pointing out that most of these operations can be optimised to some extent using itertools instead of sets

Comment: @Karsten: The point of a python `set` is to efficiently test for membership in the `set`. You cannot do that with an iterator, because the stated goal of an iterator is to provide an arbitrary sequence of items one-by-one. You need to use one or the other, but an iterator *cannot* be both. Storing your article ids in a set for efficient testing is a great idea, but it won't be an iterator.

Comment: Thanks for clearing my first question.

Strictly speaking I think you are right. However, iterators could be sets and satisfy the uniqueness if the programmer knows that this condition _must_ be met. E.g. if I fetch an article by id MongoDB ensures that there is only one article for that id. I wouldn't say that this a smooth concept, though.

You are also right that the running time would be higher but longer running time is very often the price for less memory. Sometimes this price is worth it or even inevitable if there is just not enough memory.
I very much agree with @auqavitae

Comment: @Karsten: Just to make it (more) explicit: to re-loop through the first iterator when determining the intersection leads to exponentially worse performance. For two iterators of sizes N and M, the time required to determine their intersection that way would be O(N*M). That is never a price worth paying with most real-world datasets, not when you can have a O(M) alternative after creating a set. :-)

Comment: I agree with the general idea but have a few nitpicks: "exponentially" means `a**n`. But `O(n**2)` is polynomial (quadratic) that is bad, but not as bad as `O(a**n)` e.g., non-dfa regex engines may demonstrate an exponential performance degradation due to catastrophic backtracking. Also you *can* create a generator that yields only unique items without looking at future values though it might require O(n) memory (for past values) that might defeat the purpose of using it.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: exactly, and you cannot use such an iterator to create an intersection with *another* iterator.

Comment: My intuition told me that the time complexity would be bad. I did not trust it though and I did not think that the run times by standard types are so good (http://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity).
I guess the best approach would be to load only the ids into sets do the operations needed and finally load the documents by the remaining ids.

Comment: @Karsten re: "However, iterators could be sets and satisfy the uniqueness if the programmer knows that this condition must be met." The uniqueness bit is mostly beside the point. The key advantage of sets (fast membership tests) is simply incompatible with the key advantage of iterators (no need to store all items at once). Arbitrary iterators don't even *support* membership tests without destroying the original iterator. There is no way to use either data structure where you would normally use the other.

Comment: @Karsten You can try to make a generator that caches its items and builds an index, but as soon as you do even *one* set operation it has to load the whole thing, so it's no longer a generator. And you can try to make a set that doesn't load all its items and uses full traversal to test membership, but then it's no longer a set. Combining the advantages of the two is not just difficult or a trade off, it's literally impossible.